# Inheritance between business and database objects

Tags: java, inheritance, package, sonarqube, refactoring

I am refactoring a code base in java. In that there are different packages for business objects and database objects.But most of the attributes in them are same and it came to my notice after sonar reported this. So i am thinking of making a common parent class and then all the BO(business object) and DO(objects) can extend it? My doubt is, Is it a good idea to have a common parent class for both BO and DO objects? If yes, then where can i put this common parent class? In BO package, DO package or create a new Commons package?

Example of current design:

```
Package BO:
  Class B01
{

 int a 
 int b
 //getter setter for a and b;
}
 Class B02:
{

 int a 
 int b
 int c
 //getter setter for a,b and c;
}

Package DO:
  Class D01
{

 int a 
 int b
 int e
 int lastUpdated
 
 //getter setter 
}
 Class D02:
{

 int a 
 int b
 int g
 int h
 int lastUpdated
   
 //getter setter 
}
```

Follow up question is that , is it possible to have one common grandparent for both and then one parent in both BO and DO which extends common parent and then these classes that extends their respective parents?

Comment: Why are you separating the objects, then? If those are merely POJOs that have no business logic, you should have just one of them. If there is associated business logic, you could encapsulate rather than inherit them.

Comment: these are just pojo but they share some(not all) attributes same. like there are 2 business pojo and two database pojo, but all of them have same common attributes and some different attributes that are specific to that pojo,so thats why there are multiple pojos. business pojo and database pojo are having some common attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inheritance like this, whilst initially attractive, is not a good idea as it results in very inflexible code. Whilst in the early stages of development it looks good because it results in less code, invariably business requirements change and the business objects can start to diverge from the database entities.

If you are familiar with the SOLID design principles the S stands for Single Responsibility, which means that a class should have one, and only one, reason to change. Using inheritance as you propose means that the parent class may have multiple reasons to change, i.e. when the database structure changes and/or when the business domain changes.

Business objects should serve a different purpose to your database entities. In Object Oriented development, a business class encapsulates both data and behaviour. The database entity typically only contains data. Applications tend to have mappings between various different flavours of POJO - DTO <-> Business Object <-> DAO. This ensures that your application can cope with the changes that most projects have to deal with at some point in time.